# Disrupt a game being played on wifi

Tags: technology, phone, laptop

I stay in a hostel and my roommates constantly play Mini-Militia using their smartphones and I'm really fed up of them making noises while playing.

Is there any way that I can turn off their phone hotspot using by my PC/phone so that I can be relieved?

Note: The hotspot is made on one of their phones while the rest connect their phones to that device and I want to figure out whether it can be turned off by my PC/laptop.

Comment: You cannot easily block wifi transmission with everyday household items. I think this might be a "beat em, join em or go for a walk" situation..

Comment: yes, it's kinda hacking. That's what I am asking for !!

Comment: @CaiusJard Actually you can disrupt a Wifi signal. Use a microwave oven, One of the channels is on the same frequency.  Both operate in the 2.4 Ghz band.

Comment: Yes, I nearly commented about using a microwave, but several things prevented me from doing so, aside from technical challenges of varying the frequency of the oven once the frequency of the WiFi network is determined you have the moral/ecological implications of running a multiple kilowatt device for the extended number of hours necessary as well as disrupting other people’s enjoyment. You might as well just repeatedly punch the noisy ones in the face when they start playing; at least that targets the “offenders”(and offence can only be taken, not given) rather than innocent WiFi users too

Comment: Devices do exist that aim to disrupt WiFi networks, but life hacks is all about using everyday items intended for other purposes.. a quick web search of relevant keywords should turn up a plethora of low cost devices specifically designed to cause problems for WiFi users

Comment: You wouldn't have to vary the frequency of the ovens at all. Wifi receivers would be easily overloaded. The oven frequency is in the middle of the band. 2.4GHz is shared by numerous services such as amateur radio, medical devices etc.

Comment: Instead of stopping their hotspot just join their hotspot (try finding their password somehow) and then use any app to disconnect their internet using WifiKill for Android or any other similar app. You will even find similar apps for your pc as well. Just be careful they never come to know that it's you preventing them from playing

Comment: @baba Your idea seems to be interesting !! But, they are not using the internet but just using the hotspot of one device while others are connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either by a rooted Android phone or Windows PC. Download WifiKill on Android / [Netcut](http://www.arcai.com/netcut/) on PC. Connect to the WiFi on which the game is being hosted. Now open the app and it will show you list of all devices on that network. Select the devices of your friends from the list. Now click "Grab" and then click "Kill" (on WifiKill) or click on "cutoff" (on Netcut). This will most probably stop their game.

This is how it will work:
When you will use this app, it will make other devices think your device as the access point. But your device will drop all the network packets that it will receive from their devices and stops their internet connection. Due to this same reason their game will also disrupt irrespective of the fact whether the game is utilising the internet or not.

Comment: Have you tried this at your own level? Also, it would be an "icing on the cake" situation if disruption could have been done without getting the hotspot password !!

Comment: Its been years since I have played mini militia. Also I haven't tried doing this. But strongly think this will work. But you can try it; the app size is just 2mb and the whole procedure will roughly take 10 minutes. THE SILENCE WILL BE WORTH IT 

Comment: Although you should find another way to solve your problem. If you will stop them from playing mini militia they may start playing pubg. So ultimately you will need to find a peaceful place to study

Comment: Well I have the icing on the cake. But for that you will need to dig a little deeper yourself. Also I can't assure that it will work as your laptops wifi adapter may not support the software. Try using aircrack-ng and then you will need to use the commands airmon-ng and mdk3. This will do something like a DoS attack on the host device

Comment: I have MacBook with me. Can you get into some more depth in explaining your thoughts?

Comment: There's no way this could be done on a MacBook. You will need Kali Linux installed for this. Or at least a Windows

Comment: That's no problem, I can install `Kali` on `Virtual Machine`.

Comment: If you will install Kali Linux on your virtual machine you will need an external WiFi adapter as your inbuilt  WiFi adapter will not work. You may try installing it on dual boot or the best way is creating a bootable usb or a DVD and boot from that. All I can tell after this is that search for terms like "jamming a WiFi using Aircrack-ng and DoS on WiFi network"etc.

Comment: Well, this will need some bucks for the `External WiFi  Adapter`. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. Something around ₹1500-2000

Comment: So I suggest a bootable DVD will be the best and you will need another laptop. I have never used a MacBook and don't know whether booting from an external drive is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too much for tackling those scoundrels.

Comment: I didn't get "installing it on dual boot"? Do you mean `Kali`  or something else?

Comment: As I previously said, even if you completely stop their WiF, they will start playing over the internet so it's not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's technically hacking you're asking for.

as you might have figured out that you can ask them politely to keep volume low.

if not then you should try to break up their teams by indulging them into other things just before they begin it.

or just sit there and spoil their mood by discussing your life problems.

a more tough thing to do is to make your image as very sad or something so they automatically abstain form coming close to you or prefer staying out.

or you can keep your volumes high when they are studying and make a deal to negotiate your demands, when they ask you to keep low.

least you can do from your PC is turn on your hotspot and hope for interference to play out.

Comment: Welcome to the site! A lot of this answer is psychological or based around interpersonal interaction and hence would probably be better off on somewhere like interpersonal.stackexchange.com - we specifically aim to avoid answering questions about mind hacks and by corollorary extension, answers involving "mind hacks" should be avoided too

Comment: okay.. gotcha !

Comment: @CaiusJard It's not an interpersonal question. The answer has led you believe that. The answer needs to be something technical and not what ankiiiiiii answered. The above answer is not the one I expected and I cannot downvote it due to less reputation.

Comment: @George I never said it was an interpersonal question; I said *this* was an interpersonal *answer* and answers involving mindhacks are off topic for the same reason that questions involving mindhacks are. The comment was intended to point out to ankiii that most of his answer is off topic for LHSE, and if he wants to dispense this kind of advice it probably belongs on Interp-SE. Apologies if this caused confusion

Comment: this was supposed to be a temporary "relief" till someone answers it. 
and thanks to our activity, this will stay in "active" section for quite a time.
dear @George, I feel bad that you wanted to downvote it. but I think not every answer which you don't feel right, should be downvoted. some can survive at zero too.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii In the question it is mentioned `Is there any way that I can turn off their phone hotspot using my PC`. So, your answer doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to mess with them. If their computer is configured for remote access and you know their IP address. There are command prompt functions that will allow you to remotely shutdown a computer among other things. I won't elaborate further as that would be hacking and could be illegal depending on what you do.

Comment: Not sure this approach will work unless theyve permitted this hostile person onto their private WiFi

Comment: They are not playing with their PCs. Rather, they are playing game using their smartphones. I want to stop their hotspot using my PC. I hope the question is well understood !!

Comment: @George Wait. What does "I want to stop their hotspot using my PC" mean? is the hotspot created by your PC? How is their hotspot affecting your computer? Your original complaint was about noise. I suspect there is more to this than meets the eye. In any case, there are multiple adult ways to deal with this situation that doesn't include arbitrarily deciding what roommates can and can't do.

Comment: @TimNevins You are taking it wrong !! Read the question (EDIT). The hotspot is made from one of their phones and my PC is completely independent from them.

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking for is basically, on some level, illegal. Nevertheless, it is very much possible. And quite easy to do, frankly.
Just for information, you'll need a distribution of Linux, a few tools (or programs) like `airmon-ng` and `aireplay-ng`. Apart from this you'll need a WiFi adapter that supports packet injection.

You cannot technically, turn off the hotspot, but you can jam it and render it unusable.

I'll not go into the details here, as I **do not support or advice doing this.** Be careful, it is **very illegal if you inject any packet into a network you don't own.**

Comment: Well, it's illegal if done on a bigger stage and not in smaller scale such as with friends !! I request you to kindly answer that.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider you my friend if you arbitrarily interfered in the quiet enjoyment of my life.